# Structure equivalence

Tags: bixby

So I have a structure and one of the properties is a concept of type integer. So something like:

```
structure (Thing) {
  property (id) {
    type (Id)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
  equivalence: join {
    equal-values (id)
  }
}

integer (Id) {}
```

I also have an action that outputs an array of `Thing` and a `result-view` to display it like:

```
result-view {
  match {
    Thing (things)
    min (Required)
    max (Many)
  }
  render {
    list-of (things) {
      where-each (thing) {
        layout-match (thing) {
          mode (Summary)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get it so that Bixby merges all `Thing`s that have the same `id` but it doesn't seem to being working. If my action outputs two things with the same id, it displays both of them when I want it to collapse into a single `Thing`.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I'm seeing some unexpected behavior that point to a potential issue. I'm currently confirming it. I'll be sure to update you as soon as I know more.

In the meantime, I would recommend taking care of duplicates in your Action Javascript before you return the full result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed the behavior of `equivalence` with the team and I will work to make sure the current documentation is updated to match it.

For your use case, handling duplicates in your Javascript is the correct method.